# How to read body data in a post method in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This is my method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage LoginMethod()
        {
            HttpRequestMessage re = Request;
            var payLoadJson = re.Content;

            string jsonContent = payLoadJson.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;            
            var test = JObject.Parse(jsonContent);
            string userid = JObject.Parse(jsonContent)["MyFirstValue"].ToString();
            var password = JObject.Parse(jsonContent)["MySecondValue"].ToString();
          //Rest of operation
        }
```

I am passing two parameters here and want to fetch them.
In `jsonContent` I am getting data like this:

```
         ------WebKitFormBoundarybBb6ip2FLSEzMmDq
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MyFirstValue"

 ABC
 ------WebKitFormBoundarybBb6ip2FLSEzMmDq
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MySecondValue"

 XYZ
 ------WebKitFormBoundarybBb6ip4iLSEzMmDq--
```

And getting error on the line where I am parsing `jsonContent` to `JObject` as Input string is not in correct format.
I also tried `HttpContext.Current.Request["MyFirstValue"].ToString())` but I am getting `null` value there.

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong. Thank You.

Comment: That's `multipart/form-data`, not JSON.

Comment: Why are you sending `form-data` values and then using `json` parsing in the body of the method? Also why not use objects or string parameters in the arguments of the method?

Comment: How do I solve this?@Igor I am not sending the parameter in the method because of `POST` method

Comment: What could be the solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're error is here:

```
HttpRequestMessage re = Request;
var payLoadJson = re.Content;
```

you try to assign the request content to payLoadJson but you did not initialize the request.Content proerpty.

You need to initialize the request.Content property with your encoded content like this, for example:

```
requestMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(content);
```

modify your method to accept params and assign them to your `Content`. A snippet would be:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage LoginMethod(Dictionary<string, string> postParams = null)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage re = Request;
        re.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postParams);
        var payLoadJson = re.Content;

        string jsonContent = await payLoadJson.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);            
        var test = JObject.Parse(jsonContent);
        string userid = JObject.Parse(jsonContent)["MyFirstValue"].ToString();
        var password = JObject.Parse(jsonContent)["MySecondValue"].ToString();
      //Rest of operation
    }
```

Comment: Thank You very much for answer! Is it possible to do the required task without sending the `parameters` to `method`?

Comment: Yes, you just need to assign the params to your content and that it :) just make sure, you get them in the method somehow.